# Rounded corners and gradients in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using NSAttributedString inside a NSTextView to highlight certain areas within the text. I  found it easy to change the background color and the text color, but I don't even know where to start on drawing more sophisticated things like rounded corners or background gradients, or borders.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: highlighted text mockup]

This is totally doable in a web view, but that seems like overkill for just a few extra graphic flourishes.

Comment: do you mean how to make Rounded Corners for NSTextView ?

Comment: No, I mean I want to add styles like rounded corners and gradients to highlighted portions of the text that is within the NSTextView.

Answer (score 4):

I've created an NSTextView implementation that achieves very similar look to the one you're looking to create (only the gradient is missing), the implementation is available here: http://github.com/aiman86/ANTaggedTextView:
[image]

And here's a blog post explaining my approach: http://aimannajjar.com/blog/1-How-to-Create-NSTextView-with-Facebook-like-Tags-Mentions.html#post

Answer (score 1):

You can do rounded corner with Quartz lib :

```
[view.layer setCornerRadius:7.0];
```

Everyting is possible but not as easy as a stylesheet !

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no CALayer associated with NSAttributedText or its attributes. I'm trying to add rounded corners to a portion of the text (notice the blue boxes are slightly rounded in my mockup), not to the NSTextView itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes on the range of text you want to highlight in one of two ways:

```
NSTextView *textView = ...;
NSRange rangeToHighlight = ...; // Range of characters in textView's textStorage
NSColor *highlightColor = ...;

// Method 1: less efficient
[textView.textStorage setAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : highlightColor } range:rangeToHighlight];

// Method 2: more efficient but only works for attributes that don't affect layout, e.g. color, underline etc.
[textView.layoutManager addTemporaryAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:highlightColor forCharacterRange:rangeToHighlight];
```

I'm not sure if you can use a gradient color, but solid colors certainly work.

This won't get you the rounded corners though.

You might try an NSTextAttachmentCell so you can custom render the corners.

Answer (score -2):

there are some workarounds for this problem which might help you , create a UIView with rounded corners then try to draw the NSTextView Inside it , it should work.

Comment: OP is asking about the Mac not iOS, so there is no UIView.